# How to get greatest n per group and then update another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, db2, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get the most recent price for every article in a table, and then I want to put this price into another table where the article id equals the article id for that price. I think I've gotten the "get greatest n per group" part right, by doing this SQL statement:

```
SELECT item_number, price_date, price
FROM orderline AS t1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT item_number, MAX(pricedate) AS price_date
    FROM orderline
    GROUP BY item_number) AS t2 
ON t1.item_number = t2.item_number AND t1.price_date = t2.price_date
```

This gives me a table with the item_number (aka the item id), the price date and the price.

But now I just want to take the price for every item, and put that into another table, say "itemprices". Containing columns 'item_id' and 'price'.

But the problem is that I can't access the two rows in result set with an update statement. I wanted to use the `WITH` statement, which allows me to access the two columns in my result set. I would just call the "WITH table" e.g. "latestPrice", and then just do

```
UPDATE itemprices
SET itemprices.price = latestPrice.price
WHERE itemprices.item_id = latestPrice.item_number
```

But sadly the `WITH` statement can't be used with anything else than a `SELECT`. So I need to change my approach. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm using DB2, version: v5r4m0. And the platform, which apparently goes under a lot of names is AS/400, iSeries, i5 or IBM i.

Comment: Which dbms? (Solution may be product specific...)

Comment: See my edit. Was that what you wanted?

Comment: Unfortunately, _which version_ of DB2 (and platform)?  There's a huge amount of variation among them.  Even in the DBs that support CTEs as part of `UPDATE`, it still acts as a regular table reference (like in `SELECT`), so you still have to join to it - your example solution isn't valid syntax.  Oh, the only benefit of a CTE over a regular subquery is that you can join to it multiple times.  You might also have better luck with `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the 'top' row (single pass through the table).

Comment: Version: v5r4m0. platform, which apparently goes under a lot of names: AS/400, iSeries, i5 or IBM i.

Comment: Is this an unsolvable problem (or just a hard nut to crack)?? I've done a lot of different SQL exercises the last couple of days hoping that it would help me understand how to approach this. But I haven't gotten anywhere yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM ORDERLINE T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERLINE T2 
ON (T1.item_number = T2.item_number AND T1.price_date > T2.price_date) 
WHERE T2.item_number IS NULL
```

Comment: Please add a description of how this solves the users question. Also, please read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)